# Indexing Row Values Based on Value of Each Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an 8r x 10c data frame and I want to duplicate the dataframe by dividing the values in each row by the first value in its column (i.e. 'indexing' each column, with the first value = 100).

So if I start with...

```
ColA ColB ColC
1000 2000 3000
2000 3000 9000
```

It would return...

```
ColA ColB ColC
 100  100  100
 200  150  300
```

Is there a simple command to do this, or is it some sort of loop?

Comment: When you say "data frame", do you specifically mean [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)? If you're using some other data structure, please tell us what it is (a list of lists, a NumPy array, etc).

Comment: Sorry, yes -- a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: The first column in your example has been divided by 10... should it not have been divided by 1000 (as that's the first value in the column)?

Comment: I want the first value in each column to be 100 and everything else to be indexed to that.  So the first column values are x/10 and second column values are x/20 and third column values are x/30 (etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
>>> df / (df.iloc[0] / 100)
   ColA ColB ColC
0   100  100  100
1   200  150  300
```

`df.iloc[0]` selects the first row. Divide it by 100 to get a row of values to adjust each column by. Lastly we divide the entire DataFrame by this new row of values. Division happens along axis 0 by default (i.e. downwards along each column).

An equivalent operation would be `df / df.iloc[0] * 100`.

Comment: Fantastic -- thank you.  Knew there had to be a simple way to do it.

Comment: iloc works to select the first row, but the division fails.  I'm going to assume this is my lack of Python knowledge and that I'm missing something obvious, but if anyone knows of a reason it would not work as presented please let me know.

Comment: @WDCR: do you get a particular error message when you try the division?

Comment: OK - there should be an short error message right at the bottom of the stack trace, e.g. beginning with `ValueError` or `TypeError` or something similar. What is it and what does say?

Comment: Turned out the problem was a hidden index column.  Worked around the problem another way, but seems like .iloc would work.